# Making only certain bar close to each other in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to generate combination chart with stacked column and spline.Example of categories that I have are :
'Q4 12', 'Q3 12', 'Q2 12', 'Q1 12', 'Q4 11','Forecast'

So it will have 6 bars, but I want 'Q4 11' and 'Forecast' 'touching',I mean close to each other.This is because 'Forecast' is related to 'Q4 11' category.I already read demo on [Stacked and Group column](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked-and-grouped) but still don't have idea to make only certain bar close to each other.

Here is my code, you also can view it in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/unidha/tQeF7/26/) also.Thanks for reading this.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        tooltip: { enabled: false },
        chart: {

        },
        title: {
            text: 'Desktop'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Q4 12', 'Q3 12', 'Q2 12', 'Q1 12', 'Q4 11','Forecast']
        },
        yAxis:[ {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'TAM'
            },
            stackLabels: {
                enabled: false,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                }
            }
        },
          { // Secondary yAxis
            title: {
                text: 'Share',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                }
            },
            labels: {
                format: '{value} %',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                }
            },
            opposite: true,
            min:0,max:100
        }
         ],
        legend: {
            align: 'right',
            x: -70,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 20,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
            borderColor: '#CCC',
            borderWidth: 1,
            shadow: false
        },

        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false,
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                    style: {
                        textShadow: '0 0 3px black, 0 0 3px black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'HDD',
            type:'column',
            data: [0, 30, 40, 70, 20,30],
            stack:'old'

        },
         {
            name: 'SSHD',
             type:'column',
            data: [20, 20, 30, 20, 10,0],
              stack:'old'

        }, 
        {
            name: 'SSD',
             type:'column',
            data: [30, 40, 40, 20, 50,10],
             stack:'old'
        },
        {
            name: 'Share',
            type: 'spline',
            data: [10, 20, 40, 90,70],

        }
                ]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use different series, linked to the main one. In that case you will be able to set different options for that one specific bar, see: http://jsfiddle.net/tQeF7/28/

Now you can play around with `pointPadding` and `groupPadding` like in aboce example. Or you can use `pointPlacement`, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/tQeF7/29/

Note, with the second solution, it moves only point, not the full category. In Highcharts terms categories always are taking full space and divide in evenly between each.

Comment: When I applied the code here [http://jsfiddle.net/unidha/68H4r/] it's working.But when I apply the code into the page it is not working.How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Upgrade Highcharts to 4.0.3 version.